# How do I update RSS feed with feedparser in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, feedparser

I'm working on a custom bot to send a message in a Discord channel every time a new post is made on a subreddit. With this, it just sends a link to the same post every 30 seconds, the post never changes to the most recent one. I need help figuring out how to check if a post has already been posted, as well as how to post the most recent post on the subreddit.

```
import discord
import os
import feedparser
from discord.ext import tasks, commands


got_token = os.environ['TOKEN']

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=discord.Intents.default())


@client.event
@bot.listen()
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
  task_loop.start()

@tasks.loop(seconds=30)
async def task_loop():
  Feed = feedparser.parse('https://www.reddit.com/r/askreddit/.rss')

  entry = Feed.entries[1]

  channel = client.get_channel(351023004001763339)
  await channel.send(entry.link)


client.run(got_token)
```

So I tried to fix it by

I tried to store the title as a string and compare to see if the title was the last one posted. The only problem is I can't initialize any variables outside

```
async def task_loop():
```

loop. This is also why I can't change the array to be i and then increment i. The start of the loop just changes the value of i or the string back to the starting value every time.